# When I write out a repository state with `--fossilize` in reposurgeon, does 'read' restore those markers?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, reposurgeon

When converting a repository using [`reposurgeon`](http://www.catb.org/~esr/reposurgeon/reposurgeon.html) and I write a state into the `git-fast-export` by doing:

```
prefer git
write --fossilize >nameofdump.fi
```

will a subsequent:

```
read <nameofdump.fi
```

restore the additional markers that get dumped using the `--fossilize` option, or do I have to use a separate "fossils file" via:

```
fossils write >nameofdump.fo
```

and:

```
fossils read <nameofdump.fo
```

respectively?

The point is that since I am converting from SVN I need to make use of the fossil IDs as the documentation calls them, which correspond to the respective global revision ID in SVN.

Answer (score 1):

Author of reposurgeon here.

The support for Fossil was written from specifications; I have never really tested it.

If the above is still a live issue, please file a bug repiort againat reposurgeon abd I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

After getting more acquainted to the code (of `reposurgeon` 3.10) I can conclude that **no** `write --fossilize` does not have a corresponding `read` operation and a vanilla `read` **does not** care about the `# Fossil-ID: ...` comments in the `git-fast-import` stream produced by `write --fossilize`.